# Objective-C: Pass data between two not connected View Controllers

Tags: objective-c, delegates

I have a ViewController A with a `UILabel` and a ViewController B with a `button`, so I want to update the label once I press the button. I could use delegates for this, but my ViewControllers are not connected and I can't use something like setDelegate, I don't create any instance of one in another. So basically they are created somewhere else. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: When you say “not connected”, perhaps you can clarify. Are they in the same view controller hierarchy, but just not immediate related? Or are you talking about some radical swapping out of the window’s root view controller? The way that you’ve phrased the question, you’re almost certainly going to get answers about globals, singletons, etc. But dependency injection is often preferred. But we need a little more context to advise you.

Answer (score 0):

**Variant 1:** if ControllerA and ControllerB life-time differs

Use `NSUserDefaults`. On ControllerB button click store data into NSUserDefaults, in ControllerA read data from NSUserDefaults and show in label (NSUserDefaults is also observable, so can track changes in run-time)

**Variant 2:** if ControllerA and ControllerB both currently in run-time

Use `NSNotificationCenter`. On ControllerB button click post a NSNotification with data in userInfo, and ControllerA in notification handler extracts data from userInfo and assign to label.

Answer (score 0):

Use Coordinator pattern.

Class that will create/get the 2 instances of both VCs,
and with delegates will move the data between them.
The advantage of Coordinator pattern is that your VCs can be re-used on others places (same or other project), and also the code is cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Apsperi's answer:

Notification method of changing the view controller:
In the view controller with the button on button press call:

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"refresh" 
  object:self userInfo:nil];
```

Then in the viewdidload or viewdidappear method of the label view controller place the "receiver" for the notification:

```
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
selector:@selector(mymethotochangetext) name:@"refresh" object:nil];
```

The NSUserDefault method:

In the view controller with the button save a NSUserDefualt:

```
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:somestring 
      forKey:@"myuniquekeyname"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Then in the view controller with the label you can get the saved string when the view loads and place it in the text field:

```
    self.label.text=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] 
     stringForKey:@"myuniquekeyname"];
```